# Python Do While sh functions

Tags: python, sh, do-while

I need to run a python script at the time a sh file is called and during all the time this process is running.

basically it is a python spinner during installation

```
import sys
import time

do
  def spinn():
  print "processing...\\",
  syms = ['\\', '|', '/', '-']
  bs = '\b'
  for _ in range(10):
      for sym in syms:
          sys.stdout.write("\b%s" % sym)
          sys.stdout.flush()
          time.sleep(.1)
  spinn()
while
  def installing():
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["sudo sh", "installer.sh"],shell=True)
  installing()
```

is there a way to to this on python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` waits for the subprocess to exit. Use `subprocess.Popen` instead. Then use `.poll()` periodically to check for when the process exits.

```
import itertools
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

def installing():
    null = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
    p = subprocess.Popen('echo blah && sleep 5', shell=True, stdout=null)
    #p = subprocess.Popen('sudo sh installer.sh', shell=True, stdout=null)
    return p, null

def spin(p_stdout):
    p, stdout = p_stdout
    syms = itertools.cycle(['\\', '|', '/', '-'])
    sys.stdout.write('processing....')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    while p.poll() is None:
        sys.stdout.write('\b'+next(syms))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    p.wait()
    stdout.close()

spin(installing())
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Thank you for your English fix.

Comment: it works really great!! thanks
but.. it also shows all the output of the packages being installed

    ...
    After this operation, 110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.4 2ubuntu3 [2,381 kB]
    23% [1 libpython2.7-stdlib 1,359 kB/2,381 kB 57%]                      13.9 kB/s 5min 23s![spinner animation][1]

can this information be hide?

thanks!!


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr6w8.gif